# Saving a large data set to a file in chunks

Tags: javascript

I have a use case where the user can choose to export a large amount of data. The data is received from the data store in manageable sizes. However, if I wait until all the data is loaded to the browser before saving the file, the tab runs out of memory. What I'd like to do is stream the data to an open file or append to the end of a file without loading into memory, but due to browser security this doens't seem possible. Are there any better approaches? Do I have to add a middle layer and generate the file on the server side? Thanks!

Comment: It is kind of possible actually... Well I think that still today only chrome does support it, but you can hack something with a service worker and readable streams. https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js But do you really need to have all the chunks on your page? Can't you simply let the browser download it directly to the disk in one go without holding it in memory?

Comment: How can I have the browser download it to disk in 1 file without holding it all in memory? I will look into stream saver. Thanks!

Comment: From a server? Just set a content disposition attachment header. The browser will do the streaming to disk automaticaly.

Comment: But I don’t have a file, I have thousands of records that are getting sent over the wire and I need to create the file itself on the client side

Comment: Why do you have to do it on the client side? That's a server job.